# Reading a string of unknown length from a file

Tags: c++, file, scanf

I need to read a text file that's in this format:

```
n k
S1
S2
S3
.
.
.
Sn
```

N being and integer, and S's being strings. Now, as far as I've seen a string cannot be read with fscanf function, but rather an array of char's has to be used.
The problem is that I need to set the length of the character array even though I have no way of knowing how long a word will be:

```
in = fopen("01.in", "r");

int N, k;

fscanf(in, "%d %d", &N, &k);

for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    char temp[100];
    fscanf(in, "%s", temp);
}
```

So is there a way to maybe use vectors or something?
Or maybe in the off case that this problem cannot be solved, can I convert a string of chars into a string, and then create a vector of strings?

Comment: What I mean is what if I get a string that's longer than 100 characters?

Comment: Why not use `std::ifstream` and `std::getline`?

Answer (score 5):

Why not use [std::ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) and [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) something like this:

```
std::ifstream in("01.in");

int N, k;

if(!(in >> N >> k))
{
    std::cerr << "Error reading file!" << '\n';
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

std::string line; // read lines into this

int i = 0;
while(i < N && std::getline(in, line))
{
    // deal with line here

    ++i; // keep track
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first step towards code sanity here is to stop using char arrays and start using `std::string` instead. The big difference between the two is that an array's size is set in stone at compile time, whereas a `std::string`'s initial size can be can be chosen at runtime, and it can also grow and shrink while the program runs.

> Now, as far as I've seen a `string` cannot be read with `fscanf` function,
>   but rather an array of `char`'s has to be used.

Since C++11, that's not strictly true. `std::string`s are in many ways compatible with C functions. For example, you can safely get a pointer to the underlying buffer with `&s[0]`. Therefore, you *could* technically do this:

```
std::string temp(100, '\0');
fscanf(in, "%s", &temp[0]);
```

But that has not gotten us far. Apart from some other bad things about this "solution" (unidiomatic, undefined behaviour if too many characters are read, wasteful if too few characters are read), as you can see, the original problem still persists; the number 100 is hard-coded in the program. This is the real problem, as you have also said in the comment you added:

> What I mean is what if I get a string that's longer than 100 characters?

The answer to that is: Just don't use `fscanf` anymore. Use `std::ifstream` along with the [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function. `std::getline` reads a whole line, i.e. everything until the next line break, and stores the result in a `std::string`. Size and memory management are all handled automatically for you:

```
std::ifstream is("01.in");
std::string temp;
std::getline(is, temp);
```